# "Elves on the Road" reading order

Tags: suggested-order, mercedes-lackey

What order should I read the various books set in Mercedes Lackey's Elves on the Road universe? Specifically, should I read them in

- publication order, or
- first one series, then another series, etc.

If the latter, which series should I start with?

Comment: I've been thinking about re-reading these books again and would love to know the best order to do it in. From memory when I read them the first time, the timeline seemed a bit arbitrary and there was a lot of assumed knowledge so I probably read them out of order.

Answer (score 1):

Mercedes Lackey's different series are fairly self-contained and there is little overlap in characters and events. I would recommend reading each series in published order, but not worrying too much about which order to read the series. Just start with whatever series that seems most interesting.

Answer (score 1):

The [Official Mercedes Lackey website](http://www.mercedeslackey.com/biblio_series.html) offers the following bibliography, arranged by in-universe chronology and taking into account both authorship and sub-series.

Note that they broadly (but not exclusively) follow [publishing date](http://www.mercedeslackey.com/biblio_date.html).

> **Bedlam Bard**
>
> - Knight of Ghosts and Shadows (1990) with Ellen Guon
> - Summoned to Tourney (1992) with Ellen Guon
> - Bedlam's Bard (1991 - omnibus) with Ellen Guon
> - Bedlam Boyz (1993) by Ellen Guon
> - Beyond World's End (2001) with Rosemary Edghill
> - Spirits White as Lightning (2001) with Rosemary Edghill
> - A Host of Furious Fancies (2012) with Rosemary Edghill
> - Mad Maudlin (2003) with Rosemary Edghill
> - Music to My Sorrow (2005) with Rosemary Edghill
> - Bedlam's Edge (2005) with Rosemary Edghill
>
> **Diana Tregarde**
>
> - Burning Water (1989)
> - Children of the Night (1990)
> - Jinx High (1991)
>
> **The SERRAted Edge**
>
> - The Chrome Borne (1999 - omnibus) with Larry Dixon
> - The Otherworld (1999 - omnibus) with Mark Shepherd and Holly Lisle
> - Born To Run (1992) with Larry Dixon
> - Wheels of Fire (1992) with Mark Shepherd
> - When the Bough Breaks (1993) with Holly Lisle
> - Chrome Circle (1994) with Larry Dixon
> - Elvendude (1994) by Mark Shepherd
> - Spiritride (1997) by Mark Shepherd
> - Lazerwarz (1999) by Mark Shepherd
>
> **The SERRAted Edge: Doubled Edge**
>
> - This Scepter'd Isle (2004) with Roberta Gellis
> - Ill Met by Moonlight (2005) with Roberta Gellis
> - By Slanderous Tongues (2007) with Roberta Gellis
> - And Less Than Kind (2008) with Roberta Gellis